# Selecting Items from spinner and displaying them into a layout as text

Tags: android

I am facing a problem with Spinner. I have tried many for answers but the problem still persists.
I am working on a Chicken feed app where a list of ingredients is been put inside a spinner and user can select more than one ingredient.

I am trying to select more than one item from a spinner and display it as text in a table created directly under the spinner. So how can I parse this spinner text and show it on my table?

Comment: What is the issue? Are you unable to select multiple items or are you unable to display selected items? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
   String abc;    
   Spinner spinner_name = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
   Button Submit = (Button)findViewById(button_id);

    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           abc = spinner_name.getSelectedItem.toString();

            //add abc to your table

        }
    });
```

Checkbox will be better than spinner in these purpose..

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe this is a bad design due to unwanted clicks/unwanted additions to the table. You should probably just add an "add" button next to the spinner to add it to the table, however, if you want to continue down this route, you will need to add an onItemSelected listener to the spinner. The below code should work for what you want:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        //DoStuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        //DoStuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to not use a spinner, as I don't think a spinner is designed for the purpose you seem to need it for.

I'd like to suggest using a button that triggers a Dialog that shows a list of the ingredients with a checkbox next to it. And then after you pressed the positive button you iterate over the items that were selected and add them in a ListView or RecyclerView (like a table).

This post will probably help you, [Dialogs with checkbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954196/alertdialog-with-checkbox-in-android)

I'm not totally sure what you need but I think this will help you alot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom `Spinner` item with`CheckBox` with use of `interface` when an item is checked by using interface you can add/ remove item to layout or you can use list to store data and display in layout as you wanted

```
 interface ItemsCheckedListener {
    void onItemCheckedItem(String item);

    void onItemUnCheckItem(String item);
}
```